# Which architectures are used when I compile something for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I try to understand the different architectures for iOS, and when I need which.

I have a **Hello World** example. Is my assumption correct that, if I run it in the Xcode Simulator, I need to compile everything including my dependencies for x64 (because it's running on my computer).

And for my attached iPhone it's getting compiled for only that architecture. And for Generic iPhones my example will be a multiarchitecture app (arm64 arm64 armv7 armv7e) so it can run on a variety of architectures. Is that correct?

Thanks for your insight.

P.S. So if my example links **foo.a**, but **foo.a** is just *arm64 arm64 armv7 armv7e* but not x64, I could compile my app for iPhones but not run it in my simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially correct although you have two arm64 listed above; it should be arm64 and arm64e.

As to what architectures get built, it depends on the setting "Build Active Architecture Only". The typical Debug config has this set to Yes, so it only builds for the architecture of the device that you're targeting.

A Release config has this set to No, so it compiles for all architectures specified in "Architectures", which usually `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`, i.e., the architectures you listed.

As to your PS, you are correct that a `.a` file with only ARM archs could not be linked to a Simulator target.